# In java ,what happens when renew a object?

Tags: java

Given:

```
1. public class GC { 
2.     private Object o; 
3.     private void doSomethingElse(Object obj) { o = obj; } 
4.     public void doSomething() { 
5.         Object o = new Object(); 
6.         doSomethingElse(o); 
7.         o = new Object(); 
8.         doSomethingElse(null); 
9.         o=null; 
10.     }
11. }
```

When the `doSomething` method is called, after which line does the `Object` created in line 5 become available for garbage collection?

A. Line 5
B. Line 6
C. Line 7
D. Line 8
E. Line 9
F. Line 10

The answer is D, and the explain is that when in line 7 new Object() won't new a new object it's just the object created in line 5.

I'm very confused with this, any one can help me ?

Comment: My eyes are hurting.

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: why in line 7 , there no new object was created?

Comment: I find this question in a book, and I'am also not agree with the answer.

Comment: I don't get the down votes.  It seems like a valid question to ask.

Comment: Maybe if OP had mentioned it came from a book. Without that context, it reads very confusingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write this a little more clearly and clarify the names a bit:

```
public class GC { 

  private Object o; 
  private void setObj(Object obj) { o = obj; } 
  public void doSomething() { 
     Object o = new Object(); //4
     setObj(o); 
     o = new Object(); //6
     setObj(null); //7
     o=null; 
    }
  }
```

Now, think about how long the object o created on line 4 has to live:
On line 5, you're saving a reference to it in the enclosing class. So now the reference can't be GC'd for as long as the enclosing class exists and is holding a reference to it.

Once you call setObj(null) on line 7, the enclosing class no longer holds a reference to the object created in line 4. The only existing copy of o would be the one in scope, but the variable "o" no longer refers to that initial object since you've overwritten the reference in line 6.

BTW< Your example is a bit hard to read - some formatting would've made this a bit easier.

Comment: I think you are right, The answer is D but now the reason that "new Object() won't new a new object it's just the object created in line 5." I think it's a mistake.

Comment: where you write "o = new Object()", o no longer points to the reference created in line 4.

Comment: "as the enclosing class exists and is holding a reference to it." you mean enclosing instance of the class, right?

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 sets o to a `new Object()`.  Line 7 sets o to a `new Object()`.  Each `new Object()` is, well, a new object.  So when line 7 executes, it constructs a new object and assigns it to `o`.  The previous value of `o`, which was a reference to the object created in line 5, is no longer there.  Thus the only reference to the object is gone, thus the object is eligible for garage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `after line 8` because the class field `o` is holding a reference to the Object created on `line 5`

in `doSomethingElse` you are storing a reference to lines 5 `o` in the class field `o` , so it will not be available for GC until it is nullified on `line 8`

Comment: @Dici see answer from Steve B he seems to agree with me.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. Read carefully.

**Line 1**: creating class GC
**Line 2**: creating reference(o) of Object class and it is not initialised so it will be  initialised null by implicit constructor.
**Line 3**: doSomethingElse(Object obj) method takes any object and give reference to 'o' created in line 2. It means obj and o will refer to same object.
**Line 4**: function starts
**Line 5**: new local object created with reference 'o'
**Line 6**: we pass object created at line 5 to function at line 3 which will pass reference to obect at line 2. It means both 'o' at line 2 and line 5 are referencing to same object created at line 5.
**Line 7:** local reference of line 5 now refer to new Object but old object can't be garbage collected as still line 2 is referencing to old object.
**Line 8**: we pass null which will eventually be pass to line 2 and so line 2 will now     refer to null instead of old object(created at line 5) so now it can be garbage collected. So that's the answer.
**Line 9:** object created at line 7 can be garbage collected or even if we don't write line 9, as function ends at line 10, local object will be automatically eligible for garbage collection.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, D is correct.

On line 5 you're declaring a new reference `o` which **shadows** the class level reference `o`.  Shadowing means that using `o` in this method will refer to your `o` reference created on line 5, not the one created on line 2.

So the object that you create on line 5 is originally only referred to by the `o` reference created on line 5.  When `doSomethingElse` is called on line 6, you pass in the instance which you created on line 5, and it gets saved at the class level `o`.  So now two places know about the Object; the `o` on line 2 and the `o` on line 5.

On line 7, you remove one of these.  The method's `o` now refers to a new Object.  However, someone still knows about the Object created on line 5; and that's the `o` reference that was created on line 2.

On line 8, you remove this last reference.  You change the `o` defined on line 2 to point at `null`.  Now because no one knows about that Object, it can be garbage collected.

Here's a better example of what's happening, if we don't use shadowing:

```
1. public class GC { 
2.     private Object a; 
3.     private void doSomethingElse(Object x) { a = x; } 
4.     public void doSomething() { 
5.         Object b = new Object(); 
6.         doSomethingElse(b); 
7.         b = new Object(); 
8.         doSomethingElse(null); 
9.         b = null; 
10.     }
11. }
```

This makes it a little clearer, and is functionally equivalent.